# Typing/completion in a generic container

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

Imagine this setup, where I define a generic container, with as goal to make it easy to search inside:

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Self, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar("T")
class Container(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, values: list[T]) -> None:
        self._values = values

    def search(self, column: str, value: Any) -> list[T]:
        return [r for r in self._values if getattr(r, column) == value]

class SomeData(BaseModel):
    col1: int
    col2: int
```

I would use it this way:

```py
c = Container(
    values=[
        SomeData(col1=1, col2=2),
        SomeData(col1=10, col2=20),
    ]
)

print(c.search(column="col1", value=1)) # returns [SomeData(col1=1, col2=2)]
```

This works perfectly at runtime.

I will always use this container to hold one and only one object type.

I would like to have have typing/autocompletion, only the column names of `SomeData` are allowed as parameter of `column`, but I cannot think of a way to do it.

Is it at all possible? Ideally, I would love to have a SQLAlchemy-like syntax: `c.search(col1 == 1)` or `c.search(c.col1 == 1)`.

Comment: This would probably require something like TypeScript's `keyof` operator if you want autocompletion and mypy support for a generic collection like that, but the syntax `c.search(col1=1)` or `c.search(c.col1 == 1)` (*not* `c.search(col1 == 1)` without defining special objects for every possible attribute name). Would that be an acceptable answer if I wrote it?

Comment: @jasmin It definitely would!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't help for static typing, but a syntax like `c.search(col1=1)` or `c.search(c.col1 == 1)` is easily implementable.

For `c.search(col1=1)`:

```
def search(self, **kwargs: Any) -> list[T]:
    return [r
            for r
            in self._values
            if all(getattr(r, column) == value
                   for column, value
                   in kwargs.items())]
```

For `c.search(c.col1 == 1)`

```
class ContainerColumn:
    def __init__(self, column_name: str) -> None:
        self.column_name = column_name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # Could return a special object here, for now I'll just use a simple tuple
        return (self.column_name, other)

class Container(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, values: list[T]) -> None:
        self._values = values

    def __getattr__(self, key: str) -> ContainerColumn:
        if not self._values or not hasattr(self._values[0], key):
            raise AttributeError(key)
        return ContainerColumn(key)

    def search(self, *args: tuple[str, Any]) -> list[T]:
        return [r
                for r
                in self._values
                if all(getattr(r, column) == value
                       for column, value
                       in args)]
```

You could combine the two to support `c.search(c.col1 == 1, col2=2)` like so:

```
from itertools import chain

class ContainerColumn:
    def __init__(self, column_name: str) -> None:
        self.column_name = column_name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # Could return a special object here, for now I'll just use a simple tuple
        return (self.column_name, other)

class Container(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, values: list[T]) -> None:
        self._values = values

    def __getattr__(self, key: str) -> ContainerColumn:
        if not self._values or not hasattr(self._values[0], key):
            raise AttributeError(key)
        return ContainerColumn(key)

    def search(self, *args: tuple[str, Any], **kwargs: Any) -> list[T]:
        return [r
                for r
                in self._values
                if all(getattr(r, column) == value
                       for column, value
                       in chain(args, kwargs.items()))]
```